# Notify service for changes to its view from other activities

Tags: android, android-activity, service

I have a service which has a view added via addView. I need to change view's background from other class and apply the change without the need to restart the service.
Is there any way to remove and readd the view and notify service class for changes without to stop/restart the service?

Comment: A service doesn't have a UI.  So how is it adding views to anything?

Comment: I did it by override onCreate and added the view there using windowManager and layoutParams to set background, width/height etc.

Comment: use bound services then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using WindowManager.updateViewLayout(View, Params). It should work.
Just call it from whatever class you want, by getting the view and context from the Service class.

Comment: I tried your suggestion(many different tries), but always I get nullPointerException. I added the related code to my question. Can you give an example?